# Remove occurrence of string in php

Tags: php, string

i'm beginning in PHP and i try to remove all occurrence of a string. My string is something like that.

```
'This is [a test] try [it]'
```

What i'm trying to do is remove all occurrence of the [] with the text inside the square bracket.

I want the results to be something like:

```
'This is try'
```

.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

```
preg_replace('~\[[^\]]*\]~', '', $string);
```

`[^\]]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of a closing bracket `]`, zero or more times.

Add an extra trim function to remove the leading or trailing spaces from the resultant string.

```
$string = 'This is [a test] try [it]';
$result =  preg_replace('~\[[^\]]*\]~', '', $string);
echo trim($result, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$myString = 'This is [a test] try [it]';
$myString = preg_replace('/\[[\w ]+\] */', '', $myString);
var_dump($myString);
```

Explanations:

```
/\[[\w ]+\]/g
 \[ matches the character [ literally
 [\w ]+ match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    ' ' the literal character ' '
 \] matches the character ] literally
```